# Use XSLT to do a group by on one element in an XML

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

I am trying to do a group by based on a single element "h_order_num" in XML.

**ORGINAL XML LOOKS LIKE THIS**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saphana>
   <row>
      <h_brand_code>DDH</h_brand_code>
      <h_brand_country>USA</h_brand_country>
      <h_order_num>0400000631</h_order_num>
   </row>
   <row>
      <h_brand_code>DDF</h_brand_code>
      <h_brand_country>France</h_brand_country>
      <h_order_num>0400000631</h_order_num>
   </row>
   <row>
      <h_brand_code>DDG</h_brand_code>
      <h_brand_country>Germany</h_brand_country>
      <h_order_num>0400000634</h_order_num>
   </row>
</saphana>
```

**THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saphana>
   <row>
      <Ordernumber>
         <Value>0400000631</Value>
         <LineItems>
            <h_brand_code>DDH</h_brand_code>
            <h_brand_country>USA</h_brand_country>
         </LineItems>
         <LineItems>
            <h_brand_code>DDF</h_brand_code>
            <h_brand_country>France</h_brand_country>
         </LineItems>
      </Ordernumber>
   </row>
   <row>
      <Ordernumber>
         <Value>0400000634</Value>
         <LineItems>
            <h_brand_code>DDG</h_brand_code>
            <h_brand_country>Gernamy</h_brand_country>
         </LineItems>
      </Ordernumber>
   </row>
</saphana>
```

Please help me writing an xslt for this tansformation

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are lots of [similar questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxslt%5D+grouping). Look for the term _Muenchian Grouping_ if you're using XSLT-1.0, or for the `xsl:for-each-group` instruction for XSLT-2.0 and above.

Comment: @zx485 What ever I have done is not working, tried to modify from the other posts of SO. not working. Is there anything you can help me with.

Comment: @varun1986 Post your best attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. And make sure to clarify whether your processor supports XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  Thanks you for the reply. Let me give it my best shot and post it here. Yes my processor support XSLT 2.0

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 this is rather trivial, using `<xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="h_order_num">`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Please check This code:**

```
<xsl:key name="loc1" match="row" use="h_order_num"/>
<xsl:template match="saphana">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="row[count(. | key('loc1', h_order_num)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <Ordernumber>
                    <value>
                        <xsl:value-of select="h_order_num"/>
                    </value>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('loc1', h_order_num)">
                        <LineItems>
                            <h_brand_code>
                                <xsl:value-of select="h_brand_code"/>
                            </h_brand_code>
                            <h_brand_country>
                                <xsl:value-of select="h_brand_country"/>
                            </h_brand_country>
                        </LineItems>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Ordernumber>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Note this is an XSLT 1.0 solution using Muenchian grouping, the XSLT 2.0 code is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Please Check 2.0**

        <xsl:template match="saphana">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="h_order_num">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <Ordernumber>
                        <Value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                        </Value>
                        <xsl:for-each select=" current-group()">
                            <LineItems>
                                <h_brand_code><xsl:value-of select="child::h_brand_code"/></h_brand_code>
                                <h_brand_country><xsl:value-of select="child::h_brand_country"/></h_brand_country>
                            </LineItems>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Ordernumber>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: @varun1986 if you have this code is right plz vote.

Comment: thank you for your help. Both the code snippets you pasted are correct. Thanks a lot for your help. We can connect on linkedin https://www.linkedin.com/in/varunkk/